# Multiple jQuery Animations in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, slider

**My question:**

How many animations can IE8 handle at a single time and still process the animation correctly?

**More detail:**

I have two onload recursive slider animations and it is not working in IE8.  Is there any way to optimize jQuery animations besides $('elem').stop().animate()?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide more information? What exactly 'doesnt work'? jsFiddle would be extremely helpful too.

Comment: Is it working in other browsers?

Comment: It is working in other browsers, it's just clunky in IE8.

Comment: If I remove one animation the other processes the animation much better. This makes sense, but I would think that IE8 should be able to at least handle two animations at a time. I may be wrong.

Comment: Not that much you can do about IE performance. Some of the comments on the jQuery Animate() page suggest that by adjusting the internal tick time you can improve performance (might be worth a try). http://api.jquery.com/animate/#comment-50886341